# Unexpected behaviour amending a 2d char array with FOR loop

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, char, printf

I am trying to amend each character in a 2d array using a FOR loop, but I am getting unexpected results.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    char converted[4][4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            converted[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", converted[i]);
    }
}
```

Expected result: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Actual result:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXo
XXXXXXXXXXXXo
XXXXXXXXo
XXXXo

Comment: when converting chars to strings, you must terminate them with `\0`

Answer (score 2):

Your two-dimensional character array does not contain strings: sequences of characters terminated by zero character `'\0'` and the format specification `%s` expects as its argument a pointer that points to a string.

So to output its elements you need to write

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%.4s \n", converted[i]);
    // or
    // printf("%.*s \n", 4, converted[i]);
}
```

If you want to store strings then declare your array for example like

```
char converted[4][5] = { 0 };
```

or like

```
char converted[4][5] = { "" };
```

In this case after the nested for loops you may write

```
    printf("%s \n", converted[i]);
```

because the last character of each element of the array will be zero-initialized by default in the declaration of the array.

Comment: Thanks, would there be a way of changing my loop so that it can print correctly just using %s? @vlad from moscow

Comment: @ben In this case you need to store strings.

Comment: @ben: Change `char converted[4][4];` to `char converted[4][5];` and put a null character (`'\0'`) in the last element of each row.

Comment: @ben Or put a `\n` last in each row except the last row where you put a `\0` instead. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/r3jPf9Ynf)

Answer (score -1):

You see, the way C reads a char array is it keeps reading until it finds a '/0' character, so in your 2d array you don't actually have 4 strings, you have one 16 character 'XXXXX...\0' string. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks, so would it be better to add a null terminator instead? @mercifulsory

Comment: “the way C reads a char array is it keeps reading until it finds a '/0' character” is true only for strings. C programs may use arrays of `char` other than as character strings.

Comment: @MercifulSory '/0' is a multibyte integer character constant. It seems you mean '\0'.

Comment: Then make an edit and move on with your life ;)